# I need help getting the output correct when writing and reading data to a file

Tags: c++, file

I working on an assignment for my first programming class. We've recently moved onto using files, and for some (probably obvious) reason I cannot get my output to be correct.

The program is designed to:

1. Get an unknown number of real estate agent's sales for 4 houses and 1 apartment.
2. Write these number to a file.
3. Read the data from the file.
4. Calculate each agents total sales and average sales.
5. Find the company average sales.
6. Find the agent who had the highest sales.
7. Display steps 4-6.

So far, this is what I have. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to display all of the agent's sales and average. I thought it would display all of the agent's sale information first, company average, and then the agent with highest sales.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    double hSale, aSale, totalSales, companySale = 0.0, avgSales, companyAvg;
    int numAgents = 0;
    const int HOME_SALES = 4, APPT_SALE = 1;
    char go = 'Y';
    string fileName, agentName, highAgent;

    ofstream outputFile;

    cout << "\nEnter the file name: ";
    getline(cin, fileName);

    outputFile.open(fileName);                          

    while (go == 'Y' || go == 'y')                      
    {
        cout << "\nEnter the agent's name: ";
        cin >> agentName;
        numAgents++;

        outputFile << agentName << "\n";                
        
        for (int a = 0; a < HOME_SALES; a++)            
        {
            cout << "\nEnter a house sale : $";
            cin >> hSale;

            while (hSale < 0 || hSale > 200)                
            {
                cout << "\nThe sale must be between $0.00 and $200.00. Please try again: ";
                cin >> hSale;
            }

            outputFile << hSale << " \n";
        }

        for (int b = 0; b < APPT_SALE; b++)             
        {
            cout << "\nEnter an appartment sale: $";
            cin >> aSale;


            while (aSale < 0 || aSale > 200)                
            {
                cout << "\nThe sale must be between $0.00 and $200.00. Please try again: ";
                cin >> aSale;
            }
            outputFile << aSale << " \n";
        }


        cout << "\nEnter another agent's sales? Y for yes, N for no:     ";
        cin >> go;

        while (go != 'Y' && go != 'y' && go != 'N' && go != 'n')
        {
            cout << "\nError. You must enter Y or N. Please re-    enter: ";
            cin >> go;
        }
    }
    
    outputFile.close();                                     
                                    
    ifstream textFileIn;                                        
    textFileIn.open(fileName);

    if (textFileIn.fail())                                  
    {
        cout << "\nError. File not found. Ending program.";
        cout << endl << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    double higestSale = 0.0;

    while (textFileIn >> agentName)
    {
        totalSales = 0.0;
        for (int s = 0; s < HOME_SALES; s++)
        {
            textFileIn >> hSale;
            totalSales += hSale;
        }
        
        if (totalSales > higestSale)
        {
            higestSale = totalSales;
            highAgent = agentName;
        }

        companySale += totalSales;
        avgSales = totalSales / HOME_SALES;
        companyAvg = companySale / numAgents;


        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << endl << endl;

        cout << "\nAgent " << agentName << "'s total sales were $" << totalSales << " and average sales were $" << avgSales;
        cout << "\nThe company average sales are $" << companyAvg;
        cout << "\nAgent " << highAgent << " had the higest sales of $" << higestSale;
    }


    


    cout << endl << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do the agents' names have spaces? If so, `while (textFileIn >> agentName)` will be a problem.

Comment: A note about the title: A good title is an executive summary of the technical problem you are facing and will make the question easier to find by future askers with a similar problem. My rule of thumb is if I wouldn't click the title for help in a list of search results, it's not good enough.

Comment: Also, the description says "sales for 5 houses" but you have `HOME_SALES = 4`

Comment: @001 The names don't have spaces and it's only 4 houses.

Thank you for pointing that out, I fixed it!

Comment: Please show us an example of the input you're providing, the actual output, and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 main errors.

1. When reading the file after writing to it, you don't read in the apartment data. Even though you don't need that data in the calculations, it exists in the file and needs to be read or skipped before you can move on to the next agent.
2. You print the summary inside the read loop. Don't print that info until the loop has completed and you have processed all the agents. Move the last two lines of the loop to *after* the loop.